# Exclude with the find command

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, shell-scripting, find

I need some help getting the `find` command to work right in a script working on. I need to be able to exclude some directories. Below I have what I'm doing as a work around.

```
sudo find / ( -name firefox -o -name thunderbird -o -name seamonkey \) -type f 2>/dev/null|grep -v '(10_Recommended|repo)'
```

I would like to exclude some directories so the script or `find` command doesn't take so long.

In the example above I want to exclude `/export/repo`, which is an NFS mount and  `/10_Recommended*` which is the start of a patchset used on Solaris server. The current one being an example like: `/10_Recommended_CPU_2014-01`.

I have tried using `-prune` and `!` statements and it's just not working. Can someone give me a hand with this?

I'm tuning this command on Solaris 10, RHEL 5, SLES 11 SP2.

Comment: Check out this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command) question

Comment: Thank you for posting links to other similar questions. I tried what was done in these posts and I still can't get the find command to exclude the directories.

Comment: It won't exclude everything you're looking to but I'm a big fan of the `-xdev` (also known as `-mount`) option.  It won't cross filesystem boundaries so the NFS mount will not show up.

Comment: @yoonix,Thanks for the option. The no mount option you gave me worked on the Solaris 10 server but not on the SuSe server. SLES gave me warring it wanted more arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. Below I have posted the answer to my question, or at least what worked for me. I test the below find command on Solaris 10, RHEL 5 and SLES 11.2 servers.

So below I have displayed the final find commands.

Searching for Java

```
# find / \( -name 10_Recommended* -o -name share \) -prune -o -type f -name java -print 2>/dev/null
```

Searching for Mozilla applications

```
# find / \( -name 10_Recommended* -o -name share \) -prune -o -type f \( -name firefox -0 -name thunderbird -0 -name seamonkey \) -print 2>/dev/null
```

I hope someone fins this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

`-not -path "/10_Recommended*" -not -path "/export/repo/*"`

But be careful, The path of those repositories depends on where and how you execute the find command.

If you are at `/` and you do a `find -name` whatever, you must add a `.` in the not wanted path.

For you it would be:

`find -name whatever -not -path "./10_Recommended*" -not -path "./export/repo/*"`

But if you have add a `/` like you after your find command, you must remove those dots :

`find / -name whatever -not -path "/10_Recommended*" -not -path "/export/repo/*"`

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer you gave me works on the Linux server (in my case Red Hat & SuSe). It doesn't work on my Solaris servers though. Solaris doen't like the -not or -path options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find / \( -path /export -o -path "/*Recommended*" \) -prune -o \
  \( -name iceweasel -o -name thunderbird -type f \) -print 2>/dev/null
```

The reasoning here is that the `-prune` is a sort of postfix "action", best combined with `-path`. List the paths you want ignored first, then the files you're looking for. This seems unnatural in comparison with the prefix nature of other find operations.

In this manner, the paths are seen first to be pruned, and if not, the 'other side' of the -o switch executes. The other way around, it will depth search first and the prune never gets reached, or at least that's my understanding.

Portability is going to be a problem no matter what, especially between Solaris and *nix flavors. Maybe you'd have some luck with the version of `find` in OpenCSW but no guarantees there. Whip up a small shell script and check for the OS type from `uname`, a time-honored sysadmin tradition.

Here's an example from my machine, using GNU find:

```
[fuzzed@ops ~]$ find / -path /usr -prune -o \( -name rsync -o -name bash \) -print 2>/dev/null
[fuzzed@ops ~]$ find / -path /usr/share -prune -o \( -name rsync -o -name bash \) -print 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/rsync
```

My `find` version:

```
[fuzzed@ops ~]$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
```

Also, some predicates support globbing or regex, so check that out too.

Comment: Sam, thanks for replying to my post. I tried your answer on my Solaris 10 server and it didn't work. Solaris doesn't support the -path option. I alo couldn't get the version of the find command with the command you gave me.